# ERROR: auto-makefile - NUL character / missing separator

Tags: c++, eclipse, makefile, separator, nul

OS:             Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion)

Program(IDE):   Eclipse CDT

---

I am currently learning advanced C++ using the eclipse development environment. (I have my reasons.)
The problem at hand that I have been working at for several hours now is an error occurrence during the building of my program.
Basically, a makefile is automatically generated for my project when I request a build; the problem is that the makefile itself seems to receive an error and to appears in the console as so:

```
**** Build of configuration Release for project TEST ****

make all 
makefile:1: warning: NUL character seen; rest of line ignored
makefile:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.

**** Build Finished ****
```

I have searched for a solution to both problems listed, none of which were genuinely existent.
Strangely, the first line(s) is just a row of '#' comments. Even stranger, the IDE (or the error parsers) seems confused as to where the error actually is, because the error symbol moves when certain actions are implemented.
What really bogles my mind is that this makefile was automatically generated, and I made no changes to the settings related to makefile (by default, the GNU makefile is used, but I tried  the Posix makefile with no luck.) I even reinstalled eclipse altogether.
It is worth noting that in this particular project, I included OpenGL and GLUT libraries for testing purposes; however, I attempted building a semi-empty project as well and received identical results.

If any further information is necessary, please speak up. I did not include the makefile because trying to edit it would result in an overwrite after another build.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is related to file encodings. By an editor (like NP++) check file encoding types, change to UTF-8 w/o BOM.

Check *.mk files especially, not only source files.

Comment: This solved it for me. For some reason Powershell created a UTF-16 file when I did `echo "" > Makefile` to create the file. I'm not normally a Windows guy so I don't really get logic in doing that. Anyway, thanks for this.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, somewhat solved it. Basically, my files were not in a source folder.
It is pretty ridiculous that it can't build outside a source folder, or give a proper error/ warning.